# Display values in column A and its count in an excel

Tags: csv, batch-file

I have a batch script which combines multiple textfile data into a CSV file. This is working fine and I am able to add a header as well.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

(for %%x in (ClientLog*.txt) do more "%%x") >Copy.csv

echo NAME, DATE, TIME > NEW1.csv
type Copy.csv >> NEW1.csv
```

current output:
[image]

I tried multiple options to get all the NAME(Column A) and get its count and put it in a new CSV file. But I am not able to find a right way to do it using batch. Is it possible using batch scripting?

Expected output:

NAME   COUNT

User1  10

User2  1

User3  3

User5  3

User4  2

Comment: You have been here long enough to be aware that this is not a script request service, you write the code, and if there is a specific problem with it in running, you fully explain the issue and we try to help you resolve it. Also I note that there are several of your previous questions which are not marked as accepted. Potential responders may be better motivated to help you were you to show your willingness to appreciate their help by accepting it using the official system. BTW you can use `=COUNTIF` in Excel itself to do this sort of thing.

Comment: I've helped you with at least two answers previously, and you haven't provided positive feedback or accepted my answers, _so you tell me who's demotivating who?_ Also take a look at the [tour], learn [ask] and then provide a [mcve] as I've already asked; _in order that your question is on-topic_.

Comment: I suggest to use PowerShell for this, possibly wrapped in a batch. With PowerShell it's as easy as `gc .\ClientLog*.txt|convertFrom-csv -Header Name,Date,Time|Group Name|Select Name,Count`

Comment: BTW, out of the ten previous questions you'd asked with answers, only two of them had been accepted, you've now accepted one of mine, but there are still seven others, did you miss all of them and the subsequent notifications you received for each comment and answer posted? Anyhow, as I'm sure you're aware, your image is of a spreadsheet, but your question is related to a csv file; in order to attract potential helpers, you should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50812902/edit) your question to include the csv file's layout and example content too.

Comment: Please don't post an Excel screenshot of the data, include the content of the CSV file as text within your question! Also check and correct the format of the counting file (you said it's a **C**SV file, but I cannot see a **c**omma)!

Comment: @user2163975, must we assume that you're not going to revisit the previous seven answered questions then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use PowerShell for this, possibly wrapped in a batch.

With PowerShell it's as easy as

```
gc .\ClientLog*.txt|convertFrom-csv -Header Name,Date,Time|Group Name|Select Name,Count|Export-Csv New.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

To use that script line in a batch file:

```
powershell -NoP -C "gc .\ClientLog*.txt|convertFrom-csv -Header Name,Date,Time|Group Name|Select Name,Count|Export-Csv New.csv -NoTypeInformation"
```

In PowerShell as a script without aliases but the very same commands.

```
Get-Content .\ClientLog*.txt | ConvertFrom-Csv -Header Name,Date,Time|
    Group-Object Name | Select-Object Name,Count | 
        Export-Csv New.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Some intermediate results for demonstration :

```
PS> gc .\ClientLog1.txt
User1,1/4/2018,20:00

PS> gc .\ClientLog2.txt
USer2,1/4/2018,22:00

PS> gc .\ClientLog*.txt
User1,1/4/2018,20:00
USer2,1/4/2018,22:00

PS> gc .\ClientLog*.txt|ConvertFrom-Csv -Header Name,Date,Time

Name  Date     Time
----  ----     ----
User1 1/4/2018 20:00
USer2 1/4/2018 22:00

PS> gc .\ClientLog*.txt|ConvertFrom-Csv -Header Name,Date,Time|group name

Count Name  Group
----- ----  -----
    1 User1 {@{Name=User1; Date=1/4/2018; Time=20:00}}
    1 USer2 {@{Name=USer2; Date=1/4/2018; Time=22:00}}

PS> gc .\ClientLog*.txt|ConvertFrom-Csv -Header Name,Date,Time|group name|Select name,count

Name  Count
----  -----
User1     1
USer2     1

PS> gc .\ClientLog*.txt|ConvertFrom-Csv -Header Name,Date,Time|group name|Select name,count|Export-csv new.csv -Notype

PS> gc new.csv
"Name","Count"
"User1","1"
"USer2","1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides the fact that the combining of files is completely useless for this question at all, because it works anyway (although in a quite clumsy way) and it is not at all related with the actually problematic counting part, I want to briefly show you how I would do the combining with a batch file:

```cmd
> "combined.csv" echo NAME,DATE,TIME
copy "combined.csv" + "ClientLog*.txt" "combined.csv" /B
```

Now let us determine the individual `NAME` values and store them in `indnames.csv`:

```cmd
rem // Use `NAME` values as variable names as there as no duplicates possible:
for /F "usebackq skip=1 tokens=1* delims=," %%I in ("combined.csv") do (
    set "$%%I=%%J"
)
rem // Store the found individual variable names in a file:
> "indnames.csv" (
    for /F "tokens=1* delims=$=" %%I in ('set $') do @(
        echo/%%I
    )
)
```

Finally let us count the number of occurrences of each `NAME` value in the original combined file and save the result to `countind.csv`:

```cmd
> "countind.csv" (
    echo NAME,COUNT
    for /F "usebackq delims=" %%I in ("indnames.csv") do @(
        < nul set /P ="%%I,"
        < "combined.csv" find /C "%%I,"
    )
)
```

All this works only if:

- the `NAME` values are not empty and do not begin with white-spaces;
- the `NAME` values do not contain `$`, `=` or `,`, and they do not begin with `;` or `?`;
- a `NAME` value followed by a comma `,` occurs once per line;
- no variable whose name begins with the `$` sign exists at the beginning;